# indexing excel files in PHP

Tags: php, database, excel

For a customer i'm working on a small project to index a bunch (around 30) Excel spreadsheets. Main goal of the project is to search fast through uploaded excel files. I've googled to find a solution but I didn't found an easy solution yet.

Some options I'm considering:

-Do something manually with PHPExcel and MySQL and store column information using meta  tables. Use the FullText options of the table to return search results.

-Use a document store (like MongoDB) to store the files and combine this with ElasticSearch / Solr to get fast results.

-Combination of both, use Solr on the relational database.

I think the second option is a bit overkill, I don't want to spend to much time on this problem. I'd like to hear some opinions about this, other suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: 30 spreadsheets is not a lot. How big are they? If you don't want to spend much time on this problem, it seems to me that option 1 is the best. Dump all the text data from your spreadsheets to a full text indexed table and use it for your search.

Comment: They're not that big, max. 1mb each. Do you agree that MongoDB is overkill or can it come in handy when it somehow get's bigger?

Comment: You don't necessarily need NoSQL. If you can fit your Excel files in a rigid MySQL schema, then it will works perfectly. Depending of course on what you are already using. If you already have a MySQL setup, use it. If you come to a point where the performance become an issue, you can always add a search engine over your existing mysql installation, Sphinx for example.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others. I've done several systems in the past that suck spreadsheets into a database. It is an excellent way of getting a familiar user interface without any programming. I've tended then to make use of email to get the spreadsheets a central location for reading either by MS Access and, in more recent years, read by PHP into a MySQL database.

PHP is particularly good as you can connect it easily to a mail server to automatically read and process the spreadsheets.

Comment: I did implement it a couple of weeks ago, and it's working just fine with a relational database. I see a couple of problems with much larger excel sheets but I did solve this case for now :)